# How can I select the last edited version of the post?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a question and answer website like SO. Also I have a table which contains both the questions and answers and their edited version. Here is my table structure:

```
// QandA
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| id |  title  |            body           | related | type | edited_id |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| 1  | title1  | question content          | NULL    | 0    | NULL      |
| 2  |         | answer content            | 1       | 1    | NULL      | 
| 3  | title2  | question content          | NULL    | 0    | NULL      |
| 4  |         | answer content            | 3       | 1    | NULL      |
| 5  |         | answer content            | 1       | 1    | NULL      |
| 6  |         | answer content (edited)   | NULL    | 1    | 2         |
| 7  | title3  | question content          | NULL    | 0    | NULL      |
| 8  | title1  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 1         |
| 9  |         | answer content            | 7       | 1    | NULL      |
| 10 | title1  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 1         |
| 11 | title3  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 7         |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
```

#### Column explanations:

**`related` column:**

- `NULL` for both questions and edited version of questions/answers
- `{the id of its own question}` for answers

**`type` column:**

- `0` for questions
- `1` for answers

**`edited_id` column:** *(the id of original post)*

- `NULL` means it is a original question/answer
- `{any number}` means it is a edited version of a question/answer.

---

Now I need a query to select a question and all its answers. Noted that I need to select **the last** edited version of them *(if they have been edited)*.

**Example1:** I have this value: `:id = 1` and I want this output:

```
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| id |  title  |            body           | related | type | edited_id |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| 10 | title1  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 1         |
| 6  |         | answer content (edited)   | NULL    | 1    | 2         |
| 5  |         | answer content            | 1       | 1    | NULL      |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
```

**Example2:** I have this value: `:id = 3` and I want this output:

```
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| id |  title  |            body           | related | type | edited_id |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| 3  | title2  | question content          | NULL    | 0    | NULL      |
| 4  |         | answer content            | 3       | 1    | NULL      |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
```

**Example2:** I have this value: `:id = 7` and I want this output:

```
// QandA
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| id |  title  |            body           | related | type | edited_id |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| 11 | title3  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 7         |
| 9  |         | answer content            | 7       | 1    | NULL      |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
```

---

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM QandA
WHERE (id = :id AND type = 0) OR
      (related = :id AND type = 1)
ORDER BY type -- noted that the order of answers doesn't matter
```

As you see, my query doesn't support *edited version*. Anyway, how can I replace edited version of posts when there is a edited row of that post?

**Note:** Please don't tell me *"don't keep both the questions and answers in the same table"*, Because I know it. But now I need to solve problem above.

Comment: You really need a `timestamp` column. If you had that it would have been lot easier.

Comment: @1000111 I can add a new column named `date_time` *(actually I have it in my real table structure)* .. but I didn't think it will be useful. I guess it acts exactly the same as `id` column in this case.

Comment: I think it would be easier if questions and answers were two separate tables, but anyway...

Comment: Can id==6 be related=1?

Comment: use multiple queries.  Get your Question first, then get your answers or each answer.

Comment: This is slow model. On update post - update old row as new content (keep ID) and insert old data of row as new row (new ID) (may be in trigger). Add column "old (0-current/1-old)" for speed up select actual data. Then select curent data: `select * from tab where id=NN or (related=NN and old=0)` if optimizer gives a bad plan for "OR" - `select id=NN UNION select related=NN and old=0` (create composite index on [related, old])

Comment: @Mike Sounds good .. thank you

Comment: You should also write the `related` id again on the edited record. This would make it easier to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SET @qid := 1;

SELECT 
QA.*
FROM QA 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    MAX(GREATEST(A.id, COALESCE(B.id, 0))) latest_id
    FROM QA A 
    LEFT JOIN QA B ON A.id = B.edited_id 
    WHERE @qid IN(A.id,A.related,A.edited_id)
    GROUP  BY A.type , IF(A.type = 1, A.id,0)
) AS t 
ON QA.id = t.latest_id
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bd2cc/2/1)</kbd>

Comment: Just one thing .. you query selects some rows even [when I set `@qid` the id of an answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bd2cc/3) .. well it should be like that .. It should select a question and all its answers *(the lase edited version of them)* when I set the id of a question.

Comment: This answer is supposed to work if you pass the question id. I didn't really think that you can pass id of answer too.

Comment: So, what's the expected behavior when you supply an id of an answer? @MartinAJ

Comment: No row should be selected.

Comment: Then you can add an extra condition in the where clause like [**that**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bd2cc/9/1)